# Calling a JS function from a widget from a different widget?

Tags: jquery, requirejs

How can I call giveAlert() function that's in newsletter.js from within landingpage.js?

landingpage.js

```
define([
    "jquery",
    "Ignite_Orgbf/js/js.cookie",
    "Ignite_Orgbf/js/newsletter",
    "domReady!",
    "magnificpopup"
], function($,Cookies, newsletter){
    "use strict";

    $.widget('custom.mbLandingPage', {
        _create: function() {
            newsletter.giveAlert();
            // DOESN'T WORK
...
...
...
    return $.custom.mbLandingPage;
```

newsletter.js

```
define([
    "jquery",
    "Ignite_Orgbf/js/js.cookie",
    "domReady!",
    "magnificpopup"
], function($,Cookies){
    "use strict";

    $.widget('custom.mbNewsPopup', {
        giveAlert: function(){
            alert("TEST");
        },
...
...
...
    return $.custom.mbNewsPopup;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `$.custom.mbNewsPopup.giveAlert()`.

jQuery widgets should be available on the global jQuery object. Another method can be found on the jQuery docs [here](https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/widget-method-invocation/) but this method relies on you invoking the widget on an element.

Comment: I've tried that and no go.

Comment: Damn. What happened when you tried?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $.custom.mbNewsPopup.giveAlert is not a function

Comment: What does console.log($.custom.mbNewsPopup.giveAlert) show you?

Comment: Gives an "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to my work below, where "updateQuote" is a jquery widget.

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_NegotiableQuote/quote/actions/update-quote'
], function ($, updateQuote) {
    'use strict';

    var mixin = {
        _sendData: function () {
            updateQuote()._updateTotal();
            return this._super();
        },
    };

    return function (targetWidget) {
        $.widget('mage.saveAsDraft', targetWidget, mixin);
        return $.mage.saveAsDraft;
    };
});
```